# Unable to change style in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Unable to change style, when using `$(this).addClass('errorClassText')` **in jQuery mobile**.
I really need to use $(this) as I have several form fields, where I would like to apply validation. Can someone please suggest where I could be going wrong.

jQuery script:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
        $(".form2 input").click(function() {    
            $(this).keyup(function()
                {
                    $(this).addClass('errorClassText')
                });
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

HTML code with css styling:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
        .errorClassText{
            color: #ff6666;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body> 
<form class='form2' name= "form" action="">       
    <input type="text" name="buildingname" id="house_name" >
    <label id="house_name_error" for= "house_name"></label>
    <input type="text" name="doorno" id="doorno" >
    <label class= "" id="doorno_error" for= "doorno"></label>
    <button type="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" name="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would assume that adding a class is working, but the CSS rule is not specific enough, compared to the included stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use `key up event` without `click` like,

```
$(document).on('pageinit ready', function(){
    $(".form2 input").keyup(function(){
         $(this).addClass('errorClassText')
    });
});
```

**Updated,** if you want to `addClass` for a `particular input element` like `doorno` then try,

```
 $('#doorno').on('keyup',function(){
    $(this).addClass('errorClassText')
 });
```

Comment: By using the above code, if there is any keyup event in any of the input elements, the function is being executed. Which is not desired.

Comment: Yes you can by changing the `jquery selector` like `$('#doorno').on('keyup',`

Comment: I agree by using the above instead of `$(this)` would work, this means I need to repeat for each field (I have 9 fields in a form).

Comment: use can use :not selector see http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ like `$('form:input[type="text"]:not("#doorno"))` which selects all `input elements` except `#doorno`.

Answer (score 0):

The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard. However, in your instance, you are trying to trigger within a click event (on click of .form2 input). So I would imagine your code is currently looking for the release of a key on the keyboard at the point when the user clicks into the field. Not going to happen.

If you add a console log inside of the click function and outside of keyup function, and also a different console log one inside of of the keyup function, you should be able to see what is being triggered and when (I wouldn't think the keyup function is being triggered at all).

There doesn't appear to be anything in your snippets of code which would add any inline styles to input (which would be the other reason for not seeing your error styles applied as these would override the style assigned to the new class).

Try this:

```
    $(document).on('pageinit ready', function(){
            $(".form2 input").keyup(function(){
                    $(this).addClass('errorClassText')
            });
    });
```